# updating category name with php and sql not working

Tags: php, html, forms, input, sql-update

I'm trying to update a category name with no luck...

on the functions.php i have a function to show all categories:

```
function get_all_categories(){
    global $connection;
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM categories';
    $select_categories = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_categories)) {
    $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
    $cat_title = $row['cat_title'];
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$cat_id</td>";
    echo "<td>$cat_title</td>";
    ?>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="delete_cat_id" value="<?php echo $cat_id; ?>">
        <?php 
        echo '<td class="text-center"><input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete" name="delete"></td>';
         ?>
    </form>

    <form method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="update_category_id" value="<?php echo $cat_id; ?>">
        <?php 
        echo '<td class="text-center"><input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Update" name="update_category"></td>';
        ?>
    </form>
<?php 
    // echo "<td class='text-center'><a class='btn btn-info' href='categories.php?update=$cat_id'>Update</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }

}
```

the function is shown in the file categories.php:

```
    <form action="" method="post">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="my_new_cat">Add a new category
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="my_new_cat">
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
 <input type="hidden" name="category_id" value="<?php echo $cat_id; ?>">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Category">
                                </div>
                            </form>
                <?php 
                if (isset($_POST['update_category'])) {
                include "includes/update_categories.php";
                }
                ?>
```

my code in the update_categories.php is:

```
    <?php 
        $selected_cat_id = $_POST['update_category_id'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE cat_id = $selected_cat_id";
        $select_edit_categories = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_edit_categories)) {
            $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
            $cat_title = $row['cat_title'];
        }        
        ?>
        <form method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="updated_cat_name">Update category</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="updated_cat_name" value="<?php echo $cat_title; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="update_cat_title" value="Update Category">
            </div>
        </form>
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['update_cat_title'])){
        $updated_cat_title = $_POST['updated_cat_name'];
$edited_category_id = $_POST['category_id'];
$update_cat_query = "UPDATE categories SET cat_title = '$updated_cat_title' WHERE cat_id = $edited_category_id ";
$update_query = mysqli_query($connection,$update_cat_query);
checkQuery($update_query);
}
        ?>
```

there is a button to update the category, the category name is getting into the input field in the code above.

when I click the UPDATE button a new field is revealed via  `include "includes/update_categories.php";` containing the category name inside it.

when I change the name in the input field and click "Update Category" under the new field of category name I get nothing and nothing changes in the DB.

also, no errors presented...

any ideas?
thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST['update_category_id']` is accessed first thing in your code but there is no input for `update_category_id`.

Did you missed to set a hidden input for `update_category_id` in the form?

You may edit your code to add hidden input around

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="updated_cat_name" ...
<input type="hidden" name="update_category_id"
       value=<?php echo $selected_cat_id; ?> />
```

Edit :

1. form containing `update_category_id` in "**functions.php**" should have `action="categories.php"`.
2. where is `update_category` set in "**categories.php**" that is being checked in `if (isset($_POST['update_category']))` ?
3. Can you confirm if the file "**includes/update_categories.php**" is being included ?
4. The hidden input is still missing in form in file "**includes/update_categories.php**"
5. `<input type="hidden" name="update_category_id" ...` in "functions.php" just passed to "**categories.php**" to be able to display information of selected "update_category_id", where as `<input type="hidden" name="update_category_id" ...` is required save the changes made in form in file "**includes/update_categories.php**".

Comment: please add code how to pass wariable from form to script, for example by hidden input

Comment: You would be getting category_id to edit the category, you need to use this value in your form.

Just like you're passing `$cat_title`, you need to add `<input type="hidden" name="update_category_id" value=<?php echo $selected_cat_id; ?> />` around  `<input class="form-control" type="text" name="updated_cat_name" ... `

Comment: edit you answer )) I know how to, I'm for over users

Comment: hello and thank you for the quick reply, the fields are there, i have updated the post with the supporting code.

i also tried to add a hidden post to take the value of the `category_id` :
`<input type="hidden" name="category_id" value="<?php echo $cat_id; ?>">`
and still nothing...

Comment: @ahiadhazan : check the edits. `<input type="hidden"` is still missing from update category form in "update_categories.php"

can you also check if correct value for "name" attribute is "category_id" or "update_category_id" !

Comment: hello @ViralIP ,  i added in the post the hidden field i used inside the form, still nothing, no errors are shown and the SQL is not updating...

Comment: 1.You have to add `<input type="hidden" ... ` in my answer in your " update_categories.php" file.     
2. You're picking `$edited_category_id = $_POST['category_id'];` which is not set in update form.        
3. You should try `echo` your `$update_cat_query` to confirm if your query is built correctly.

Answer (score 0):

OK

After a long searching for the answer including the wonderful people here trying to help, I have figured it out.

The problem was in this code:

```
if (isset($_POST['update_category'])) {
include "includes/update_categories.php";
}
```

The problem was that when i clicked the "Update" button created in the code above, it included the query for getting the value from the SQL field AND the query to update the value in the SQL.

The thing is when i click the "Update" button again in the code above, the POST is changing to `if(isset($_POST['update_cat_title']))` instead.

The result is that the `if (isset($_POST['update_category']))` POST in no longer avaliable, which causes the `include` of the form to be removed.

Therefore, the UPDATE query is no longer in this page and the results are not sending.

So i put this:

```
    if(isset($_POST['update_cat_title'])){
    $newCatName = $_POST['updated_cat_name'];
    $catId = $_POST['category_id'];
    update_category($newCatName, $catId);
    }
```

(could have put all the function in the same file but decided to move it to the "functions.php" file instead).

So i created this function:

```
function update_category($newCatName, $catId){
global $connection;
$updated_cat_title = escape($newCatName);
$edited_category_id = escape($catId);
$update_cat_query = "UPDATE categories SET cat_title = '$updated_cat_title' WHERE cat_id = $edited_category_id ";
$update_query = mysqli_query($connection,$update_cat_query);
checkQuery($update_query);
header("Location: categories.php");
}
```

Now everything works great,
Thanks All!